# Why is my fire simulation blocky even with 5000 resolution divisions?

Tags: fluid-simulation, resolution

For some reason, my fire simulation is really low resolution even if i set it to a crazy number of divisions. why is this happening?
[image]

here it is with 5000 resolution divisions
[image]

here it is rendered out

Comment: It would be ill-advised to display the full resolution in the interactive viewport. How does it look rendered out?

Comment: Oh ... What kind of setup has to be used to sim res 5000? ;) There matters what is the longest edge of your domain to say if it is or is not enough.

Comment: my setup for baking 5000 res is my mac air. that shouldn't be possible but somehow it is working?

Comment: also, i just rendered it out, it looks the same, quite blocky.

Comment: also i have adaptive domain on, not sure if that helps

Comment: perhaps the answer is to do 100000 resolution :) also sorry i sent so many comments

Comment: How huge is this domain?

Comment: provide your blend file - your informations are too modest

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post.  This question is getting close votes because it lacks details or clarity.  You've made some comments where you give more information, we prefer that you edit your question to include these details (and more).  Once you've made your edit, your question will be automatically queued for review to be reopened.

Comment: @supercriticalpotatohead People keep asking how huge your domain cube is. Usually I make smoke simulations with divisions of 150-250 or 500 if I want them highly detailed. So again, if this is 5000, what is the size of your domain? And for the rendered image, this looks like Eevee to me. Are you working in Eevee or Cycles? If Eevee, what Render Settings for Volume have you got? As Allen said, your question is getting close votes because it's lacking of details what you've actually done.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, i looked at the size of the domain like you told me to and it was actually huge, so i scaled it down and now it works fine.